# How can I set range to the random library

Tags: c++, random, numbers

I really don't like the rand() function.I wanted to use the  library but I don't really know how to set up a range for example from 1 to 3. I want to "random" these numbers(1,2,3) and not huge numbers like 243245.This code is how you can use the random library and print random numbers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    minstd_rand simple_rand;

    simple_rand.seed(NULL);

    for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ++ii)
    {
        std::cout << simple_rand() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: fyi Entertaining talk by Mr STL on using <random>  https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
    int main()
    {
        std::random_device rd;  //Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
        std::mt19937 gen(rd()); //Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 3);

        for (int n=0; n<10; ++n)
            //Use dis to transform the random unsigned int generated by gen into an int in [1, 6]
            std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
```

Thanks to @holyBlackCat Credit to: [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

Comment: Obligatory note that while `std::random_device` is usually the preferred method of seeding, it doesn't work on MinGW (i.e. gives the same result every time the program is run).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat What do you mean? the code does not output the same number all the time

Comment: Are you using MinGW?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I guess not

Answer (score 3):

Use [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution):

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 rng(std::time(0)); // `std::minstd_rand` would also work.
    std::uniform_int_distribution d(1,3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        std::cout << d(rng) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it gives me an error though with "uniform_int_distribution d(1,3);"

Comment: I posted my own answer though

Comment: @Nope It means your compiler is outdated, or isn't configured to use the latest C++ standard.

Comment: That's is not ture at all you forgot <> but the number are not changing

Comment: @JesperJuhl look it my answer

Comment: @Nope You don't need `<>` since C++17. It works for me.

Comment: @Blastfurnace My code has <> because it doesn't work if the code doesn't have it

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Do you know why when i create a function for it it all gets messed up?